# SQL Server : how do I make a list that has dates and facilities that are not in another table?

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @StartDate date = '08/01/2021', 
        @EndDate Date = '08/04/2021';

with cte_FacilityReportingDates as 
(
    select distinct Facility, REPORTING_DATE 
    from table1 a  
    where REPORTING_DATE between @StartDate and @EndDate
),
cte_facility as
(
    select distinct Facility 
    from table1 a 
),
cte_ReportingDates as 
(
    select distinct a.REPORTING_DATE 
    from table1 a 
    where a.REPORTING_DATE between @StartDate and @EndDate
),
cte_Combine as
(
    select * 
    from cte_facility f 
    cross join cte_ReportingDates d
)

select t1.FACILITY, t1.REPORTING_DATE from cte_Combine t1 where not exists (select 1 from cte_FacilityReportingDates t2 where t1.FACILITY = t2.FACILITY and t2.REPORTING_DATE between StartDate and EndDate and t2.FACILITY is null group by t1.facility, t1.REPORTING_DATE)
```

I've got it down to the last 50 of the race (Hat Tip to the Olympics) but can't get over the finish line.  I know it is simply something I've overlooked but I'm racking my brain!  I need to show the facilities and dates that are NOT in the result from cte_ReportingDates.

Comment: Aren't you just over a `NOT EXISTS` here?

Comment: That's what my mean by something simple.  I can't get not exists to work!!!!!

Comment: So show us that attempt; the above isn't a complete statement as you don't actually have a (final) `SELECT`.

Comment: select
    t1.FACILITY, t1.REPORTING_DATE
from
    cte_Combine t1
where
    not exists
    (select 1 from cte_FacilityReportingDates t2 where t1.FACILITY = t2.FACILITY and 
     t2.REPORTING_DATE between StartDate and EndDate
    and t2.FACILITY is null  group by t1.facility, t1.REPORTING_DATE)  --I know the startdate and enddate are param but it won't let me add the @  the error message is 'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.'

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper formatting, you will encourage others to help. You removed the efforts that someone else made in formatting your code when you edited it. That was quite discouraging honestly.

When formatted properly, you can clearly see where each CTE is defined and better understand what each does. Seems you overdid your use of DISTINCT - don't just throw it into code in hopes it "fixes" something. The first cte (cte_FacilityReportingDates) does not really need DISTINCT if used to test for existence. TBH that particular CTE it is a bit overkill since the logic can easily be incorporated within the EXISTS clause below - but that is a style choice.

```
<with  ... all your CTEs from original query ...> 
select comb.FACILITY, comb.REPORTING_DATE 
from cte_Combine comb 
where not exists (select * from cte_FacilityReportingDates as trn 
    where comb.FACILITY = trn.FACILITY 
      and comb.REPORTING_DATE = trn.REPORTING_DATE)
order by ...;
```

There is no reason to apply a GROUP BY clause to the final query since it is nothing by a unique set of <FACILITY, REPORT_DATE>. Any time you use/see such a clause with no aggregates, that should be a concern that the writer has lost the path.

Also notice the ORDER BY clause. If the order of rows matters, then the query that generates the resultset must have one. Usually it does matter.

I also used better table aliases. Cryptic ones are not not helpful to the reader; develop good habits. I have no idea what the CTE named cte_FacilityReportingDates (which selects from "table1" - another crap name with equally crap alias "a") so I just made up something.

The last issue I'll highlight is the rather important assumption you made. Your logic assumes that every facility exists within table1. That is not usually a safe assumption for some sort of "activity" table (which is my guess as to what that table represents). The same applies to dates. For dates you can generate the set of all dates between two boundaries easily - I'll leave that adjustment to you if needed. You cannot do with for facility - you might (likely do or should) need another table for that.

Comment: Yes, every facility exists in table1.  That's why I used a cross join to get all facilities and all reporting dates for the cte_combine.  Thanks for the help!  I got it to work!